# Is there any reliable jQuery multiselect that is searchable AND has clickable optgroups?

Tags: jquery, optgroup, searchable

I've been using the jquery multiselect with the `enableClickableOptGroups: true` option enabled and its fine. However it does not allow me to search though the values.

Tried Select2. That is searchable and has optgroups, but unfortunately the workarounds if found to make them clickable were laggy and unreliable.

Is there any alternative I didn't see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end found a component that did the job:

https://springstubbe.us/projects/jquery-multiselect/